# Sequence to sequence prediction transformer : need for normalization

Tags: deep-learning, sequence, normalization, transformer-model

I am trying to create a transformer model for sequence to sequence prediction using structured data.Do we need to normalize the input data? As a standard transformer architecture already has a layer normalization implemented already.

If we need normalization,how should it be normalized? Only the input to the encoder or the decoder input also needs to be normalized ? But, the decoder input is essentially the output we will be generating.How can I normalize ( local normalization) each sequence with their mean and std ?